# Ajax equivalent of UrlHelper.Action in Asp.Net MVC 3.0

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I generate an AJAX URL in my .cs file in MVC 3.0?

Normally I use this code for a normal URL: 

`UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);


string link = url.Action("actionName", routeValues)`

But I'm looking for a way to create some sort of a link, like the one you create in a View with 

`@Ajax.ActionLink("linkText", "actionName", routeValues, ajaxOptions)`

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does it mean in your cs file? In your Controller? Do you mean in a cshtml file? In a custom Html Helper? In what context? Also, it's kind of unclear (at least to me) what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this answered for my AjaxHelper extension.  I had to use MergeAttributes and ToUnobstrusiveHtmlAttributes Here is the relevant code:

```
        Dim anchorBuilder = New TagBuilder("a")
        anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(action, controller, routeValues))
        anchorBuilder.MergeAttributes(AjaxOptions.ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes)
        anchorHtml = anchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)
```

Link to my question:  [Custom AjaxHelper extension, merging AjaxOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525778/custom-ajaxhelper-extension-merging-ajaxoptions/6526198#6526198)